# Unable to locate package Nginx-module-GeoIP

Tags: nginx, debian, geoip

I am working on Debian Jessie 9. I have installed Nginx but there is no GeoIP module.

so I decided to install it but "apt-get install nginx-module-geoip" not working giving an error like E: Unable to locate package Nginx-module-GeoIP

how I can install GeoIP module in Nginx

Comment: Jessie is Debian 8, not 9. Did you mean Debian 8, or did you mean Debian Stretch (9)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/dynamic-modules/geoip2/) it looks like the command for Debian/Ubuntu is this:

```
apt-get install nginx-plus-module-geoip2
```

Note that [NGINX plus needs to be installed](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-plus/), not just regular NGINX

I've been using the MaxMind free geolite2 database module, but it hasn't been updated since 2015 and only runs on Python2.  Is the NGINX module more recent?

Comment: You may use GeoLite2 Free Geolocation Data, which is getting updated on weekly basis, and it's free. just need some simple scripts to put them all together.